# what is equivalent of "mmddhhnn" datetime format in Visual Studio .NET?

Tags: .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a VB 6 source code, and I am rewriting it in .NET
At some places I have found a date is converted into "mmddhhnn" format. I am not sure what is "nn" here, also if I put as it is in .NET, then it doesn't convert nn into anything rather it remain "nn" only. What is its equivalent in .NET?

Comment: I would suggest taking an approach of finding out what your current code does, before trying to port it. The question of what "nn" means in VB6 has nothing to do with .NET. Decouple the "understanding current code" from "migrating to new code" parts. (It looks like Oded has your answer in this case, but you should think about this as a general approach. You can't tell whether or not a migration is successful if you don't know what the code is *meant* to do.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET equivalent is:

```
MMddHHmm
```

See [VB6 format strings for dates and times](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6) and [those for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: +1 And here is a link to the relevant [official VB6 manual topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263414(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @MarkJ - That's a nice link, but it is a VBA reference, not VB6.

Comment: True enough, but it seems to be the only relevant documentation on MSDN & it's linked from the "See also" in the [VB6 topic on Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262745(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: @MarkJ - Heh. How... interesting of Microsoft to do that.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch04/04-03-CustomDateTime.htm) `nn` means minutes with leading zero.

So this should be equivalent:

```
Dim dateString = date.ToString("MMddHHmm")
```

Uppercase `MM` means months and lowercase minutes. Uppercase `HH` means hours in 24 hours, lowercase using a 12-hour

[**MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings in .NET**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: The joys of multiple date/time formats in Microsoft products! ;o)

Comment: @Westie: Don't associate VB6 with _joy_ ;-)